# Place an "X" in a number of cells based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a timesheet that a user can enter the number of days worked, and then the macro will place an `X` in the appropriate number of cells starting with a specific cell, and eventually skipping certain cells.

I can get it to put an `X` in the cells in a specified range, but not the user-defined Range.

```
Sub WorkDays()

    Dim days As String

    days = InputBox(Prompt:="How Many Days Worked", Title:="Days Worked", Default:="Enter Number of Days Worked")

    Dim number As Range

End Sub
```

I am trying to automate our company's unique timesheet.

Edit: Here is the code that puts Xs in a few of the cells I want them in. The problem is I want the "days" variable to be the cell range, that the Xs are put into.

```
Sub WorkDays()

Dim days As String

days = InputBox(Prompt:="How Many Days Worked", Title:="Days Worked", Default:="Enter Number of Days Worked")
days = "X"
Range("D11:D15").Value = days

End Sub
```

Here is a screen shot of the worksheet.

[image: Timesheet with X'x Added in the D11 through D15 rows]

Comment: Can you include the code that puts the "X" in the range? It would also be helpful to show what the sheet looks like and what the "user" range is on the sheet.

Comment: Added the stuff you asked for

Answer (score 0):

In your second sub, the second `days =` means the first one is useless as `"X"` replaces whatever value `days` had before.

Try:

```
Dim days As Long

days = InputBox(Prompt:="How Many Days Worked", Title:="Days Worked", Default:="Enter Number of Days Worked")

Range("D11:D" & 10 + days).Value = "X"
```

Note: The problem appears more complex than stated. How do you know someone worked Mon-Fri as opposed to Wed-Sun (both are five days). You may need more than one input box to determine the starting day of someone's week.

Comment: You are correct, This is just the beginning. In our company we can earn flex days when out in the field by working Saturdays and Sundays. My end goal, is to have a multi input box where we can enter days worked, flex days earned, and what week/weeks it was during. Company policy also requires us to apply a digital signature in the form of a picture of our signature, print as a pdf, and email it. I want to include a button to do all that in one click. This is also my first time using VBA. I really appreciate all the help.